Isekai manga where the main character is reincarnated as a final boss in a game
I don't remember the name of the manga, but the art style is similar to the manga "Hell Mode: Yarikomi Suki no Gamer wa Hai Settei no Isekai de Musou Suru" where the main character is the final boss.

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Anything else you could [edit] in to help narrow down what you're looking for? You remember the art-style, do you remember any characters or places? Anything about the video game the MC is reincarnated into?

This is not a unique description. There's at least two where a woman reincarnates as the optional superboss; one where a guy reincarnates as the (female) final boss; and one where the guy reincarnates as the final boss, just off the top of my head. Do you remember anything at all about the characters or plot details of this story?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Considering the OP has found what they were looking for, keeping this question closed as needs details is pointless. This question should be reopened

It is still extremely vague and does not even mention the gender of the protagonist, let alone any other plot details. If the full title is "Reincarnated as the Mastermind Behind the Story", then the answer doesn't even match the one non-unique plot point: the protagonist isn't the final boss.

I found it "Reincarnated as the Mastermind"
